# GatsbyJS, using scss module with gatsby-plugin-sass getting warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, gatsby

I'm following a GatsbyJS tutorial to get to know the "framework". It's all going dandy until I try to use the module functionality of the Gatsby sass plugin. I have the SCSS file in a components folder with a number of components, renamed it to include the `.component.` part. In one of those components I would like to use the styles from that SCSS file, I import the file set the `className` value for a component but nothing changes in de development served page and the terminal claims that I have defined a variable but never use it `4:8  warning  'navstyles' is defined but never used no-unused-vars`.

```js
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

import navstyles from "../components/nav.module.scss"

const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link className="{navstyles.someclass}">Link text</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

These are my dependensies:

```json
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^2.24.66",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.3.14",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  },
  ...
}
```

Now if I just normally import the SCSS file with the declared styles. Just put the classes in the markup like `className="someclass"` those styles get used on the page no problem. But I would like to use the styles to be scoped to the component. What is my dyslexic brain missing?

I've been searching the internet but can't find a thing, which indicates to me that the solution should be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`className` is a string

```
<Link className="{navstyles.someclass}">Link text</Link>
```

If you view the rendered page, you are mostly going to see this:

```
<a class="{navstyles.someclass}">Link text</a>
```

Fix it like this:

```
<Link className={ navstyles.someclass }>Link text</Link>
```

Comment: You are my hero. Exactly something my dyslexia overlooks, even though I can imagine anyone overlooking two double quotes...but most people would catch the mistake fairly quickly.